# How do I call a Word Macro with parameters from JScript

Tags: vba, ms-word, jscript

I have a Word template with a macro defined in the ThisDocument section:

```
Sub Go(pID As Integer, pPassword As String)
```

I am trying to execute this macro from JScript as follows:

```
application.Run("Go", 1, "secret");
```

But this fails - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found one answer:

1. remove the parameters
2. use document variables instead:

   ```
   document.Variables.Add("id", 1);
   document.Variables.Add("password", "secret");
   application.Run("Go");
   ```